# Core Data, i cannot open my .xcdatamodel, which is red

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have been running tests towards a Core Data model (SQLite3). I now need to do some minor changes in the .xcdatamodel but it is red in XCODE and i cannot open it. I also deleted the sqlite2 database but that did not help.

Anyone that could give me a hint why this is and how i can do the changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Red indicates the file is missing (or XCode is looking in the wrong place for it). Have a look in your project folder to see if the file is around somewhere. If not, you'll need to restore from a backup or recreate it.

If you can find it, copy it into your project folder (if necessary) then select the file, choose Get Info from the File Menu, click the Choose button next to "Path:" and locate it, and you should be set.

Comment: but i can still run the program and it access the database?

Comment: i went back in Time Machine and found the model and it is now restored. A BIG thank you. I just wonder how and why it was deleted.